# sed + replace only if match the first word in line

Tags: sed

The following sed command replaces the `OLD` string with the `NEW` string.
My target is to replace the `OLD` to `NEW` only if `COMMAND` word appears as the first word in the line.
How to fix my sed syntax in order to replace `OLD` with `NEW` only if `COMMAND` is the first word in line?
(Note:  `COMMAND` word location could be after some spaces from the line beginning.)

lidia

```
sed "/^ *#/b; /COMMAND/ s/OLD/NEW/g"  file

  COMMAND OLD
  OLD COMMAND
```

after sed exe:

```
  COMMAND NEW
  NEW COMMAND
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
"/^[ \t]*COMMAND/ s/OLD/NEW/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: `'s/^(\s*COMMAND) OLD(.*)$/\1 NEW\2/'`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution

`awk '{if($1=="COMMAND") $2="NEW";print}' temp.txt`